# testing mysql etl using java and junit tests

Tags: mysql, etl

I would like to test an etl process I have built out in java to load data up in mysql.  Basically I would like to create an in memory database of mysql and then load data then run queries against it to make sure I have what I think I have.  What is the current best practice for doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a already a bunch of [related questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=mysql%20%20test%20java), but I will share what I did for myself: using [jcabi](http://mysql.jcabi.com). It's *not* `in-memory` , but it starts a real live mysql instance and tears it down after the test.
Another thing: you would then have `integration test` for this, not `unit test`.
[Read about the difference](http://www.typemock.com/unit-tests-integration-tests) and see if you like this.